# Converting bigger string in a tabular format

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2007

I have been asked to work on a month-end report. Data is huge and cannot be done manually in a short span of time. I need to seek advice what formula can I use to get a desired result.

In column B I have few strings separated by comma which I need to get in separate columns. I need count of each category in their respective column as shown in the picture.

Please let me know which formula should I use.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code

```
Sub Test()
Dim a, x, c, i&, j%, k%, n$

a = Range("B2").CurrentRegion.Value

For i = 2 To UBound(a)
    x = Split(a(i, 1), ",")

    For j = LBound(x) To UBound(x)
        n = Empty
        For k = 1 To Len(x(k))
            If IsNumeric(Mid(x(j), k, 1)) Then
                n = n & Mid(x(j), k, 1)
            Else
                c = Application.Match(Split(x(j), n)(1), Rows(2), 0)
                If Not IsError(c) Then a(i, c - 1) = n
                Exit For
            End If
        Next k
    Next j
Next i

Range("B2").Resize(UBound(a, 1), UBound(a, 2)).Value = a
End Sub
```

Another solution using regex

```
Sub Test()
Dim a, x, c, i&, j%, n$, re As Object

a = Range("B2").CurrentRegion.Value
Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
re.Pattern = "(?:(\D+)?(\d+))|(?:(\D+)(\d+)?)"

For i = 2 To UBound(a)
    x = Split(a(i, 1), ",")

    For j = LBound(x) To UBound(x)
        n = Empty
        If re.Test(x(j)) = True Then
            n = WorksheetFunction.Trim(re.Replace(x(j), "$1 $2 $3 $4"))
            c = Application.Match(Split(n)(1), Rows(2), 0)
            If Not IsError(c) Then a(i, c - 1) = Val(Split(n)(0))
        End If
    Next j
Next i

Range("B2").Resize(UBound(a, 1), UBound(a, 2)).Value = a
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much. you saved my time. appreciate your help. Just one question `Range("B2").CurrentRegion.Value` does not pick up the last row because there is a blank row above. how to include that too? Thanks

Comment: You can use this line instead `a = Range("B2:N" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row).Value`

Comment: Great. Thank you so much

Comment: Thanks once again. My complete report is ready within deadline. Thanks. God bless !

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can simply use an Excel function:

```
=IFERROR(TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT($B3,SEARCH(C$2,$B3)-1),",",REPT(" ",255)),255)),"")
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: nice formula based answer. thank you so much

Comment: @Justyna MK Great solution +1

Comment: Thanks @Justyna MK once again. One observation - for some values, it outputs as text to i had to add `INT()` to it.

Comment: Thanks @Sabha, the adjustment makes sense! Glad it worked for you.